# How to assert Url of new tab with WDIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, assertion, automation-testing, wdio

My test scenario is that:

1. You go to `url1`
2. you click button
3. you open another tab with `url2`

How to I assert the `url2`?

I use `assert(browser).toHaveUrlContaining('')`
But it assert the `url1`, so my test was fail

Comment: Have you used `switchWindow` to switch first ? Can you add your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the browser switchwindow method as you can see here: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/switchWindow/

By doing that I assume that your test would be something like:

1. You go to url1
2. You click button
3. You open another tab with url2
4. You switch tab (browser.switchWindow('https://theUrlYouWant.com'))
5. Assert browser.getUrl() is 'https://theUrlYouWant.com'

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Hi, it works. But if you are able to switch to the url2, you technically don't need to assert it again

Comment: Hi! Glad it helped. I understand your point. I would just like to give you two insights on this:
1) when reading or reviewing the implemented test case, it will be clearer for the reviewer to understand the purpose of the test.
2) depending on how the browser.switchwindow method behaves when the url is not found, it makes sense to leave the assertion (e.g. imagine that if the method didn't find the url it wouldn't raise an error, by not having the assertion the test would pass even when it should'nt).
Did it make sense? 
Have a nice day!